# requestAnimationFrame not pausing my background color transisition

Tags: javascript, css

I have a header with a background color of transparent which will change to black when the user scrolls. Since I am using the requestAnimationFrame to accomplish this, the transition should pause when the tab is not active to save resources. I tested this with a function counting to 300 which indeed did pause when the tab was not active and resumed to 300 when active. However, it seems that my header's background color transition does not pause when on a new tab.

I am using mozilla's example which says "This example optimizes the scroll event for requestAnimationFrame." So I think it should work well with my use case (which it does) I would just like some insight as to why my transition doesn't pause when on a different tab to save resources and be as optimal as possible. Thanks!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

```
"use strict";
// Reference: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector);

let lastKnownScrollPosition = 0;
let ticking = false;

function doSomething(scrollPos) {
  // Do something with the scroll position
  if ( scrollPos > 0 ) {
      $("header").style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
  else {
    $("header").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(lastKnownScrollPosition);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

Here is my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Boros/zjwyamvq/3/

Comment: ... This MDN example is unfortunately completely wrong, `scroll` (and resize)  events already do fire in painting frames, throttling through `rAF` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I opened https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/10580. As for your actual issue, the transition is powered by CSS, not by requestAnimationFrame (by the way, please include this part too in the question itself), so the animation may indeed not be "paused", or at least, it's very probable that it will be "delta-time based", i.e they record the start-time, and every time they have to paint a new frame they check how long time elapsed from that start-time and render the state it should be, even if it was actually paused in between.

Comment: Have you considered using IntersectionObserver to test for scrolling rather than having to invoke JS on every scroll event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach would be to use an IntersectionObserver.

If you place a tiny (1px x 1px) element at the top of the page you can set an IntersectionObserver on it which will tell you as soon as it goes out of the viewport or comes back in.

That way you only have to run JS when there is a change from the user having scrolled away from the top - which will happen only once until they scroll back up to the top.

I don't know how much more efficient this is than using the traditional scroll and trying to throttle it, but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) says:

> sites no longer need to do anything on the main thread to watch for this kind of element intersection, and the browser is free to optimize the management of intersections as it sees fit.

The very fact that you aren't coming back to execute some JS every time the user does a scroll must help regardless of whether the browser does additional optimisation.

Here's a trivial example. It adds the 1px div, sets an IntersectionObserver on it and if the div goes out of the viewport that means the user has scrolled and if it is in the viewport the user has scrolled back to the top or the system is at the start position.

Note, if you want to make it slightly less sensitive you can set the check div to have a height of say 20px so if the user scrolls back to pretty near the top the color changes.

```js
const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector);
const check = (entries) => {
  $("header").style.backgroundColor = (entries[0].isIntersecting) ? 'transparent' : 'black';
};
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(check);
observer.observe($("#checker"));
```

```html
<div id="checker" style="width: 1px; height: 1pc; position: absolute; top: 0; left; 50%;"></div>
<header style="width: 100vw; height: 200vh; transition: 5s;">SCROLL DOWN TO SEE BACKGROUND COLOR CHANGE TO BLACK</header>
```

Comment: Though the question is about the "transition", which is powered by CSS and for which an IntersectionObserver won't change anything.

Comment: Yes it is, but as it was interested in optimisation, and as you pointed out the scroll optimisation attempt was faulty, it seemed worth pointing out a different method to achieve some optimisation - and it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Was it? Your comment was fine I think. Also, instead of making your tracker bigger, you can use the margin properties of your observer.

Comment: This is definitely what I needed instead of the scroll event, but I'm having trouble understanding how some of the code works. Is the "entries" parameter considered an array? What I understand is that the "checker" div is sent to the "entries" parameter, then it is checking if the 1st element of "entries" is being intersected. Why is it checking the 1st element of entries when there is only one div "checker" that is being passed to "entries"? Shouldn't it just check if the "#checker" div itself is being intersected?

Comment: Yes, entries is a collection of elements so if we had set several elements to be observed then several might be reporting a change at the same call to the function. So one would do a forEach there. However I knew that there could only be one element reporting so I didn’t bother setting up a loop.